# How can I use the 365 office API to edit text from a PPT file?

Tags: office365, office365api

I need to upload a document to office365, extract text from all slides of the PPT document, edit said text on our web app, then save the new text back to the original PPT document in the same place.

Is this possible? If so, how can the API be used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using o365 logging and reporting capabilities and you can do this in PS cmdlet as well. Check out this link on how to do it: https://blogs.office.com/2015/07/08/announcing-new-activity-logging-and-reporting-capabilities-for-office-365/

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to extracting and replacing data within a document (whether it be a PPT or DOCX). Can you be more specific as to how the reporting capabilities can accomplish this?